# Android: display the contacts' list with one contact selected/active

Tags: android

I have an application that stores the Contact_ID of contacts. I managed to retrieve the contact_id-s from the phone's Contacts. In some cases I want to make it possible to the user to either call or send a message to the given person behind that contact_id. I don't want to store phone numbers if possible.

So I have a contact_id and I'm wondering whether it is possible to display the list of the contacts with the name behind my contact_id preselected ?

cheers